# How to background css with php variable

Tags: php, css

i just have this css style.

```
<style>
    #weatherblock{
    font-family:"Futura Md", "Futura Md BT";
    color:rgba(51,51,51,1);
    background-image:url("VARIABLE HERE");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius:20px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:400px;
    height:220px;
    background-size:cover;
    z-index:5;
    font-size:20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
```

I want to put a  variable image where it ways "variable here". I dont know if put $img or '`$img$`. Also i dont know how to define the variable of an `img`. `$img = 'img.png';` ??

Thanks

Comment: What server do you use? Also, do you have any PHP experience at all?

Comment: PHP is not a server. Common servers are Apache, Nginx, lighttpd, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the PHP code.

```
<?php
$img = 'img.png';
?>

<style>
#weatherblock{
font-family:"Futura Md", "Futura Md BT";
color:rgba(51,51,51,1);
background-image:url("<?php echo $img ?>");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border-radius:20px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:400px;
height:220px;
background-size:cover;
z-index:5;
font-size:20px;
vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
```

It will be replaced by $img. Obviously, it has to be a .php file.

Comment: Um, actually it need not be a .php file. All depends on how your web server is set up. You just need to ensure that your web server is set up to handle the file name extension as a PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend injecting variables into your CSS definitions via server side code (the bulk of your CSS should be in an external style-sheet anyway).

Either have different backgrounds:

In stylesheet

```
.background-1 {
    background-image: url(image1.jpg);
}

.background-2 {
    background-image: url(image2.jpg);
}
```

In HTML

```
<div class="background-<?php echo $background; ?>">
    // Something
</div>
```

Or do the CSS inline:

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $background; ?>);">
// Something
</div>
```